# "cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone", but the function is not overloaded anywhere

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I know there are several questions on this, and I get why this error is supposed to happen. But I'm finding it in a setup like this one:

`some_config.hpp`:

```cpp
auto initConfig(int i, char** a) -> CustomConfigType;

struct CustomConfigType
{
    // ...
};
```

`some_config.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "some_config.hpp"

auto initConfig(int i, char** a) -> CustomConfigType
{
    // ...
}
```

`configs_loader.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "some_config.hpp"
// ...
CustomConfigType config = initConfig(i, a);
// ...
```

The `initConfig` function name does not occur anywhere else in the codebase, yet I still get this error while editing in VSCode with the C/C++ Extension Pack installed while working inside WSL (I haven't compiled this code yet as there, this is only shown in the editor).

As there is no overload actually in place, any idea why this could be happening?

This is my `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                // Other libraries here
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: You need to forward declare `CustomConfigType` before specifying it in the trailing return type. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-RYK1HqHl)

Comment: "...  I get why this error is supposed to happen." and then "Any idea why this could be happening?"... ? "I haven't compiled this code yet" why not? A compilers error message is usually a lot more helpful than trying to understand what your IDE is trying to tell you

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/f3xs5MxY7

Comment: Hi @AnoopRana, thanks! It was indeed a forward declaration issue, I opened the question with the answer already included in case it happens to anyone else, as the editor was complaining about an overload instead of the actual problem.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I meant that I know what causes a "cannot overload" error but didn't know why it was happening when no overloading was being done (at least intentionally. See john's comment to my answer and also my previous comment).

Comment: ok. I completely agree with john. I tend to ignore such "while typing error reporting" tools. Compilers have much less false positives and their error messages are much more helpful

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You're right, I hadn't compiled the code as it was part of a larger and not complete project so it would have had many more errors. I should have extracted to a small playground and compiled there as in the demos already shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the error wasn't exactly related to `CustomConfigType` being unknown at the point of the `initConfig()` declaration and complained about invalid overloading instead, but placing the `CustomConfigType` declaration **Before** the `initConfig()` function declaration made the editor error go away (see [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c))

This begs a question on how the initial `initConfig()` function declaration was checked (by VSCode's C/C++ IntelliSense?) when having the then *unknown* `CustomConfigType` return type.

Comment: IntelliSense doesn't build a C++ AST, it's more of a gloss level parser.  (IntelliSense does **not** use the same parser that the compiler uses.)

Comment: Probably it just assumed `int` (or something) and then when it found out what it really was then it had a conflict based on the two return types of `int` and `CustomConfigType` IntelliSense doesn't try to do a proper parse of C++ code. It just a quick and dirty hack to try and give as much help to the programmer as possible. Personally I always turn it off.

Comment: @Eljay: AFAIK, Intellisense currently uses Edison Design Group's compiler as its basis. It **definitely** creates an AST. Past Intellisense versions (VS2010?) worked differently, but that resulted in major failures with templated code. John's comment is right, though: the EDG compiler is augmented for Intellisense to work on incomplete code - it's after all used in an editor. The semicolon at the end of the current line is almost certainly not typed yet.